# Ubuntu in VMware : VT-x not supported?

Tags: vmware, virtualization

When I open Ubuntu VMs, (Including other ones)Ialways get this if I enable VT-x.

> Virtualized Intel VT-x/EPT is not supported on this platform.
>
> Continue without virtualized Intel VT-x/EPT?

Yeah, I am very confused about that.
Any fixes?

Thanks
(SORRY FOR BAD ENGLISH, I AM INDONESIAN)

Answer (score 3):

That suggests that the host system supports neither VT-x or EPT technologies so trying to turn it on is folly. This is a hardware limitation. You need a computer that supports this CPU feature. I'm not sure what else I can say about it.

If you're certain that your computer does support either protocol, check the BIOS. I know mine allows me to turn it off (it was on by default). Mine is in my advanced CPU settings.

But otherwise, no, there's no fix other than you getting a better computer.

Comment: Maybe true, VT-x works in my Intel i7, 8 gigabytes, with VT-x active.

Answer (score 0):

Last time, on Windows 10 and Windows 11 we faced this issue after installing the Docker Desktop software which is also a virtualization software

Solution: Turn off Virtual Machine Platform and Hyper-V

Note that if there is a software causes this error, such as Docker Desktop that software might not work because it relies on the above settings.

And you don't need to uninstall either software just switching the 2 above settings on and off for each software is a way around.

Tutorial source if you don't know how to turn them off: https://mayviti.com/vmware-virtualized-intel-vt-xept-is-not-supported-pc-fixed/

Comment: Hyper-V is unlikely to be the cause given the age of the question. A more likely, by far, reason is simply the CPU not supporting virtualization, something very common in entry level consumer grade products back then.